# respond_to is acting weird in my create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following controller (pretty basic).

```
class ActivityTypesController < ApplicationController
  respond_to :html

  def show
    @model=ActivityType.find(params[:id])
    respond_with @model
  end

  def new
    @folder = Folder.find(params[:folder_id])
    @model = @folder.activity_types.build
    respond_with @folder, @model
  end

  def create
    @folder = Folder.find(params[:folder_id])
    @model = @folder.activity_types.build(params[:activity_type])

    if @model.save
      flash[:notice] = 'hoorraaaaayyy'
    end

    respond_with @folder, @model, location: root_path
  end

  def edit
    @folder = Folder.find(params[:folder_id])
    @model = ActivityType.find(params[:id])
    respond_with @folder, @model
  end

  def update
    @folder = Folder.find(params[:folder_id])
    @model = @folder.activity_types.find(params[:id])

    if @model.update_attributes(params[:activity_type])
      flash[:notice] = 'yeeeeaaaaaaah'
    end

    respond_with @folder, @model, location: root_path
  end
```

The interesing thing is: the `:location` option within the `#create` action is ignored, while in `#update`, it is honored.

I have no idea, why this is the case. Even stranger: when removing the `:location` within `#create`, it seems to stay on the `#update` action and renders the `edit` view, instead of redirecting to the `#show` view.

Has anybody an idea how I could track this problem down?

Comment: Try doing this `respond_with @model, location: root_path` I don't think you really need the @folder

Comment: I was unsure about this, too, and I tried it, but it didn't have any effect. I'm a bit unsure what `respond_with` does behind the scenes, anyway - I don't need it to expose the instance variables to the views, right? So what exactly do I need the call for?

Comment: From what I understand it works in conjunction with the respond_to at the top of your page so you don't have to write a respond_to block for every action.

Comment: Actually, I just realized, if you're doing a redirect to the root_path, you don't even need the responds_with, you can just do a redirect_to root_path.

Comment: Thank you, I guess you are right, with your first point about not needing a respond_with block for every action. But what's the respond_with useful for, then? I see that it does some magic when for example update is called, according to [RailsCasts](http://railscasts.com/episodes/224-controllers-in-rails-3?view=asciicast) it is said to automatically call the edit action, right? But why do I need to pass the @product to respond_with in #update? I'm still a bit confused about what's really going on there.

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem.

We had a view `activity_types/create.html.haml` which only rendered the `_form.html.haml` partial (this seems to be a leftover of a previous unclean implementation or workaround of the new/create action combo).

Because `respond_with` always checks for a corresponding view first, after creation, it rendered the `create` view which looked the same like the `edit` action. So if you run into something like this, too, make sure you don't have any views that prevent `respond_to` from redirecting to any other action.

Any by the way: if you only accept `:html` requests, then you only need a `respond_with` call in the `create` and `update` action, so it automatically renders the `new` and `edit` form when there are errors. If you, however, want to serve for example JSON or XML and have `respond_to :xml`, then you need a `respond_with @my_model` in the `#show` action, too (and any other action that should respond with data to a `my_action.xml` call).